# Count number of items in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I know this question is quite trivial, but this is my first day of using pandas, so please at least post a link to the document which I should read.

Basically, I don't know how to count the number of items of each column. Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    "Grade": [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1],
    "Major": ["Science", "Art", "Engineering", "Science", "Science", "Science", "Science", "Engineering", "Engineering"]})
```

I expect the following result:

```
Grade   Major           Number
1       Science         3
1       Engineering     2
1       Art             0
2       Science         2
2       Engineering     1
2       Art             1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['Grade','Major']).size().reset_index(name='Number'))
   Grade        Major  Number
0      1  Engineering       2
1      1      Science       3
2      2          Art       1
3      2  Engineering       1
4      2      Science       2
```

If need add missing values per group, add [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['Grade','Major'])
         .size()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='Number'))
   Grade        Major  Number
0      1          Art       0
1      1  Engineering       2
2      1      Science       3
3      2          Art       1
4      2  Engineering       1
5      2      Science       2
```