# How to plot bar chart in Python using matplotlib.pyplot ? Argument height must be 'xxxx' or scalar

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart, data-science

I have a data frame named 'train' which has number of variables. One such variable is 'industry'. The first 10 elements of column 'industry' are as follows:

```
train['industry'][:10]
0    Office supplies    
1    Unknown            
2    Misc services      
3    Social services    
4    Unknown            
5    Manufacturing      
6    Social services    
7    Office supplies    
8    Entertainment      
9    Construction       
Name: industry, dtype: object
```

I am trying to plot a bar chart using matplotlib.pyplot as plt library with industry type on x-axis and their frequency on y-axis. I am not really sure what to should be the value of 'height' argument?

```
plt.bar(train['industry'], height = )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count number of items in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084598/count-number-of-items-in-pandas)

Comment: the height parameter is how tall you want bars to be. So that means `x` is the sequence of unique industries in your dataframe, and `height` is the number of times they appear. `pyplot.bar` doesn't do the the counting for you.

Comment: @PaulH So do I have to  separately count their frequencies in order to plot? In R it's so easy with ggplot2 -_-

Comment: With `pyplot.bar`, yes. With other high-level libraries, you can do it one step. matplotlib is intentionally a low-level library, though.

Comment: `seaborn.factorplot` can do this in one step: http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.factorplot.html

Answer (score 0):

Height is your frequency. Here's an [example](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/ticks_and_spines/custom_ticker1.html#sphx-glr-gallery-ticks-and-spines-custom-ticker1-py)

1. Make array of length `len(train.index)`
2. Make your bar chart without the industry names - `plt.bar(array, frequency)` . The frequency/height cannot be a string. It needs to be numerical. If it isn't, convert it using [`pd.to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html)
3. Put industry names into an array
4. use `set_xticklabels(industries)` to change the labels

Comment: What is exactly meant by `plt.bar(array, frequency)`? How exactly it is to be used?